# git status stuck after unzipping repository folder

Tags: git

I just zipped (using .7z) a repository for backup before trying `git rm --cached .`

I indeed regretted the decision, since using git add after was taking way too much. I aborted the add command, deleted the folder, and extracted the backup.

Now git status doesn't work, it never completes..`git gc`worked and `git fsck` shows some dangling blobs...I have no idea whats going on

Comment: difficult to say... Can you add a screenshot what the result of `git add` is?